# Determine the above series convergence or divergence: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\log n)^x $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working on the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\log n)^x
$$

I want to determine the above series convergence or divergence.

I try to use the ratio test:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} [\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}]^x<1
$$

So that means $$x\log[\log(n+1)]-\log(\log n)]<1$$

Comment: What range has x, for x>=1 it is divergent.  so first you have to find x so $(log(n))^x $converges to zero faster than 1/n. To Nimu Basak, you have the wrong function

Comment: I think you're more likely to show this by establishing a relationship with $\sum 1/n$ -- in the long run, $(\log n)^x < n$ no matter how big you make $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use any complicated formulas to solve this infinite sum. Just look for the last term in the infinite sum, or the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log^x(n)$ This limit diverges to infinity, making this infinite sum diverge onto infinity.

Comment: this is the same as Bob's answer

Comment: I just saw that, but I didn't copy him.

Comment: Note that this works only with $x\ge 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Using Cauchy Condensation..

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^nf(2^n)$
Converge or diverge together.
Now $$v_n=2^nf(2^n)=2^n(\log 2^n)^x=2^nn^x(\log 2)^x$$
Then $$\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}=2\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^x$$
$$\implies\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}=2$$

Hence$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^nf(2^n)$ is divergent ,and so$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ is divergent for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

For $x\geq0$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log^x n\to\infty$$
hence the series diverges by the $n$th-term [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand).

Comment: @NimuBasak it is the same as $(\log n)^x$.

Comment: @NimuBasak. Yes in my notation $\log^x n$ is $(\log n)^x$ in yours.

Comment: @bob I'm pretty sure it is $(\log n)^x$ and not $(\log x)^n$. Anyways the answer is good. (+1)

Comment: @bb_823. It is, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @bob  I think the limit test fails here when$ x\le 0 $because when $x\le 0 $  ,$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\log n)^x=0$. When$ x\gt 0$ , the test works fine..

Comment: Similarly, if $x=0$, then each term is 1, so again the limit of terms is not 0.  If $x < 0$, then you'll need some other approach; for example, you should be able to prove that $(\log n)^x > \frac{1}{n}$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler. Yes, so the series is again divergent as the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: @NimuBasak. Yes, the $n$th-term test is inconclusive for $x<0$.

Comment: @bob this  series is  a series of positive numbers ,for all x.

Comment: I guess technically, since the series starts at $n=1$, the first term is only defined if $x \ge 0$, and possibly not even defined if $x = 0$.